# CSS: Referencing A URL by SubString in @namespace selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

**I am trying to create a CSS @namespace for a URL who has a list of query strings being appended to the end dynamically.**

For example:

Lets say that my base URL is: *"www.sample.com/sample"*

At the end of my URL is a list of parameters, followed by the `document.refferer`:

*"www.sample.com/sample?Param1=1&Param2=2&rf_sb=`{{document.refferer}}`"*

I would like to set a `@namespace` in my CSS stylesheet based on `Param2` of the URL:

```
@namespace foo "{{url selector}}";
```

..yet I am not sure what syntax to use to select a substring of the URL. All examples I see for using `@namespace` use the literal URL:

```
@namespace foo "www.sample.com/sample?Param1=1..."
```

..but I cannot use a literal URL declaration due to the fact that the query string is dynamically appended to the URL and could contain anything. I need to do something like:

```
@namespace foo *"Param2=2"*
```

*..the asterisk is meant to be a "wild card"*

Can this be done? Is there a proper syntax for doing this? And if so, where can I find more information on this? Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand why you want to do that. Namespace URLs are just identifiers with no real meaning. The reason for using them is to be able to write things like `svg|circle { }` and associate `svg` as used in the rule with the namespace of the `svg` element in the markup. It's most unusual to have a namespace with query parameters. What is the use case for that? Can you show the HTML and CSS you plan to use with these dynamic namespace URLs with query params?

Comment: @torazaburo I started to explain why when I wrote the question, but the explanation was very long and convoluted. Just believe me that what I am attempting to do is valid and narrow.

Comment: Good for you @torazaburo

Comment: Fine @torazaburo , I have multiple page templates in UnBounce that are all including the same form from SharpSpring. I need the form to be styled differently on each page, even though it is the same SharpSPring include on each page. I cannot style the form from the parent page (obviously, since it is in an iframe as SharpSpring does) so I must style the form within the iframe by including a global stylesheet within the SharpSpring form itself. Therefore, I must know which template I am being included in from the stylesheet within the iframe by referencing a query string in the URL.

Comment: All of this craziness is being done for very specific marketing purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the `off-topic close` vote @torazaburo . That was very un-called-for, as my question is very valid about coding.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm still not convinced that you understand CSS namespaces. They are meaningful if and only if the elements in your mark-up are namespaced. They are a way to conditionalize type selectors to match only those elements with a matching (in the sense of the namespace URL) namespace. They are not merely a way to segregate or group sets of rules, as namespaces are in some languages. I don't claim to understand your problem or your proposed solution, but are you really going to have namespaced elements in your X/HTML that you need to address using CSS namespaces?

Comment: No, what I am doing could definitely be described as a hack and I am definitely not using namespaces for what they were initially designed for, yet if what I was trying was a success, the outcome would have been very useful. I've determined that I do not need the substring of the namespace and that I can, in fact, accomplish what I am trying to do without it, and that is to have a page (included through an iframe) styled differently based on a query string appended to the end of the page's URL. `@namespace template1 "https://www.sample.com/test?template1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. A namespace in CSS can only be associated with a single, complete namespace name, not a partial match thereof. See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-namespace/#declaration).

The only place in CSS where you can perform a substring match is in an attribute selector. Depending on where the `xmlns` attribute is declared (assuming these are XML namespaces), you might be able to get away with something like

```
:root[xmlns\:foo*="Param2=2"] .foo
```

or

```
.foo[xmlns\:foo*="Param2=2"]
```

(notice the escaped `\:` in lieu of a proper namespace prefix)

As you can see, though, this is as close to a hack as it gets.

Comment: Well that stinks... Thanks though

Comment: hmm... that second suggestion is pretty interesting. I'm definitely going to give that a go. Thanks!